# How do I edit ConfigurationManager.App/ConnectionSettings while in an .Net COM Object called by asp-classic web page

Tags: c#, com, asp-classic, app-config, config

I am instantiating a .NET COM object and would like to update the **ConfigurationManager.AppSettings** and **ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings** properties.
I have noticed that even though I have settings in the assembly config file, e.g. **"ComLib.dll.config"** those settings are not available at runtime.

I make a call to create the COM Object from an ASP Classic Web Page using the following:

```
Dim COMObject
Set COMObject = Server.CreateObject("COMAPI.COMObject")
```

I use my VS2010 debugger to step into the Constructor of my .NET COM Object (COMAPI.COMObject).  This is the point were I inspect the **ConfigurationManager** to check what is loaded.

Both **"Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly"** and **"Assembly.GetCallingAssembly"** have the same result which is the full path to the **"ComLib.dll"** assembly registered location.  Which is what I expect.  This location also has the **"ComLib.dll.config"** file, which is not pulling through into the **ConfigurationManager**.

When I try to clear the **AppSettings** using the following command an exception occurs:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Clear();
```

The exception is: **"Server object: 006~ASP 0177~Server.CreateObject Failed~80131902"**

My thoughts are that the above exception is the ASP Classic interpretation of "AppSettings is read-only" but I am not 100% sure.

What I move onto, is loading the **"ComLib.dll.config"** file and then running over each of the **AppSettings** items adding them to the **ConfigurationManager.AppSettings** set but that causes an exception as well: **"Server object: 006~ASP 0177~Server.CreateObject Failed~80131902"**.

The code I use in the .NET COM Object is as follows:

```
Assembly comApiAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
string comApiLocation = comApiAssembly.Location;
configuration = null;
configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(comApiLocation);
var toLoadEnumberable = configuration.AppSettings.Settings.GetEnumerator();
while (toLoadEnumberable.MoveNext())
{
    var current = (KeyValueConfigurationElement)toLoadEnumberable.Current;
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Add(current.Key, current.Value);
}
```

I need my configuration information in the **ConfigurationManager** as this .NET COM LIB is used to make calls to other .NET Assemblies.  The other .NET assemblies require configuration.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get some [help from the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/5a8b35df-8b7c-4473-8433-bc0ee4f7c445).

Basically instead of using .Clear/.Add/.Remove on the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings I access a setting, if it exists or not, and set a value for that key:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"] = "KeyValue";
```

This updates the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.  This is great because as I access parts of my application which are out of scope from the initial "ASP Classic" -> "COM API" call I am still able to get Application Settings from the ConfigurationManager.

With all this said, I still don't know how to edit the ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.

If I try **.Clear** / **.Add** / **.Remove** on **ConnectionStrings** an **exception occurs**.  Any ideas on this issue?

I will update this answer if I find more info.

**As an update**:  To get around the ConnectionString settings not having my settings, I have implemented the Unity Container IoC framework.  I use a Static instance to host the IoC container and resolve my instances that way.

By doing this I can register my Interfaces against Class Types at the COM API which means I can pass the Connection String Settings, via Constructor Injection, I want to the resolving instance as the Connection String Settings are in scope.